# Mute logging in TPU estimator

Tags: tensorflow, logging, tensorflow-estimator, verbosity, tpu

I am using BERT `run_classifier` and tensorflow `TPUEstimator`, each time I train my model or I predict using the estimator predictor, I get too many logging information printed on my screen. How can I get rid of this information. The following line is printed million times:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Dequeue next (1) batch(es) of data from outfeed.
I0423 15:45:17.093261 140624241985408 tpu_estimator.py:540] Dequeue next (1) batch(es) of data from outfeed.
```

Also the following line is being written on my screen million times (although there is no problem and the model is trained using TPU properly)

```
E0423 15:44:54.258747 140624241985408 tpu.py:330] Operation of type Placeholder (module_apply_tokens/bert/encoder/layer_6/attention/output/dense/kernel) is not supported on the TPU. Execution will fail if this op is used in the graph. 
ERROR:tensorflow:Operation of type Placeholder (module_apply_tokens/bert/encoder/layer_6/attention/output/dense/bias) is not supported on the TPU. Execution will fail if this op is used in the graph.
```

This is the code which produces this verbosity:

```
from bert import run_classifier
estimator = tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimator(
  use_tpu=True,
  model_fn=model_fn,
  config=get_run_config(OUTPUT_DIR),
  train_batch_size=TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE,
  eval_batch_size=EVAL_BATCH_SIZE,
  predict_batch_size=PREDICT_BATCH_SIZE,
)

input_features = run_classifier.convert_examples_to_features(prediction_examples, label_list, MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, tokenizer)
predict_input_fn = run_classifier.input_fn_builder(features=input_features, seq_length=MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, is_training=False, drop_remainder=True)
predictions = estimator.predict(predict_input_fn)
```

How can I ask the model not to print them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to [set the logging verbosity level](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/logging/set_verbosity) with

```
tf.logging.set_verbosity(v)
```

at the first line of your `main()` method, where verbosity level `v` could be:

```
_level_names = {
  FATAL: 'FATAL',
  ERROR: 'ERROR',
  WARN: 'WARN',
  INFO: 'INFO',
  DEBUG: 'DEBUG',
}
```

where `v=tf.logging.FATAL` will print the least amount of logs.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. but there is no way to have the info but not the error? I mean if set the log verbosity to INFO, ERROR will be included in the output as well?

Comment: That's by design. Error is a more severe condition than INFO. When a lower level of logging is on, all higher level of logging is also on.